# onclick event of the link button inside the reapeator control fires at the time of binding data to reapeator control

Tags: asp.net, onclick, repeater, linkbutton

I have a `Linkbutton` inside a `Repeater`  control.
My code in the aspx page :

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnOpenSuplmnt" runat="server"  
 Text= "OpensupLink"
 OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ClaimId", "return confirm(\"Reopen the assignment for claim {0} to issue a supplement?\")" ) %>'
    OnClick ='<%# lnk_OpenSupplement(Eval("ClaimId"))%>'> 
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then on the code behind

```
protected string lnk_OpenSupplement(object profileId)
        {
            string retStr = "success";
                  .........
            return retStr;

        }
```

In the page_load :

```
  repeater.DataSource = recentAssignments;
                    repeater.DataBind();
```

The strange thing happening here is : in the Repeator's databind the `lnk_OpenSupplement` method gets fired, which is unwanted functionality. How can i avoid this. or can some body point out where am I going wrong.

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're databinding the output of that method to the `OnClick` event.

Meaning, you're saying `OnClick = "success"`, which isn't what you're expecting to happen.

`<%# something %>` means 'Execute something when binding this element and use the return value here'.

I'd recommend you take a look at how to bind command arguments to the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event.

Here are some articles that describe how to do this:

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/03/repeater.html

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/custom-buttons-in-the-datalist-and-repeater-vb

After hooking up the event, your button would then become:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnOpenSuplmnt" runat="server"  
      Text= "OpensupLink"
      OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ClaimId", "return confirm(\"Reopen the assignment for claim {0} to issue a supplement?\")" ) %>' 
      CommandName="MyCommand" 
      CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ClaimId") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Agreed. Using `ItemCommand` would be the better solution, instead of using `OnClick`.

Comment: Can you post your repeater control's code and the `OnItemCommand` from the code behind? Also, in Page_Load, you'll have to put the repeater binding inside a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` block.

Answer (score 2):

I think the <%# tag for the OnClick is evaluating the function on databind, try removing that and changing it to:

```
  OnClick ='lnk_OpenSupplement'
```

You will have to work out the "ClaimId" on the server side as well, but you should be able to do that using the standard event arguments that would get passed into lnk_OpenSupplement.

Comment: I get "Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line"

Comment: More complete answer than mine. :)

Comment: really, you probably want to follow Jims advice about commandarguments.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is the following line:

```
OnClick ='<%# lnk_OpenSupplement(Eval("ClaimId"))%>'>
```

The `<%# ... %>` tag will be triggered during data binding. Effectively what the code is doing is executing lnk_OpenSupplement on data binding, and assigning it's return value to `OnClick`.